# Troubles creating NSIS installers on windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, nsis

I'm having some absurd problems with NSIS, suppose the simplest possible hello world nsis file:

```
outfile "hello_world.exe"

# create a default section.
section

# create a popup box, with an OK button and the text "Hello world!"
messageBox MB_OK "Hello world!"

sectionEnd
```

Now nsis generates an hello_world.exe without any errors, and the file looks correct.
But trying to run it on windows 7 in my virtual machine gives the error

/path/to/hello_world.exe The specified path does not exists

which is quite strange because it's exactly the same path and it does exist.
The funny thing is that running the same executable from *wine* instead works perfectly!

Any idea about what it could be?

Comment: FYI, I have tested your code sample in my Win7/64 without any problem, the message box displays correctly. You could give a try withe the profiling feature of the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what it is try to do. Perhaps that you have another program that is doing some mess like an antivirus ?

Comment: Maybe try a windows path on windows...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it is is quite amazing.
That file which I was trying to run it's on a shared directory provided by virtualbox, shared from my Linux box.

Now running NSIS installers on these paths just doesn't work, while trying to run any other exe is just fine.

Copying the NSIS installer somewhere else works perfectly fine, with the same file..

Comment: Well thanks but I already found the problem and I really don't want to investigate further in the Redmond crappiness...

Comment: Who says the problem is in Windows?

Comment: An operating system that when you click on a file says that the path on which you're clicking does not exist to me sounds already quite guilty.
It might also be a bug in the virtualbox sharing maybe, but surely the Windows error message is ridicolous.

Comment: Did you try staring it from cmd.exe ?

Comment: NSIS reads itself which might be a uncommon operation, other than that it does not use any weird API calls and runs on Win95 etc.